# Poisson Binomial probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have 2017 coins, such that the probability of tossing heads with each coin is $\frac{1}{2018}$, $\frac{2}{2018}$,......... $\frac{2017}{2018}$. We toss each coin once. Find the probability that the number of heads tossed is even.

So the total number of possibilities is $2^{2017}$.

Suppose we toss 2 heads - the number of possibilities will be 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 2017 \\
 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 However, we would need to multiply by the probabilities as each coin is biased, so for this case we would need to multiply by

$\frac{(1)(2)+(1)(3)+...........(2016)(2017)}{2018}$

This already is a big computation to make. Doing the other possibilities with 4, 8 and 12 heads seems impossible to do by hand. Is there some key observation that I am missing here?

Comment: I think you could argue that the result is 0.5 by noting that P(x Heads) = P(x tails) = P(2017-x Heads)

Comment: If it is 0.5 then the fact that the number of coins is odd is important, because the answer to the analogous problem with 2 coins is not 0.5.

Comment: I don't see any relation with Poisson or Binomial distributions or processes. Could you think of a title which actually relates to the question?

Comment: The distribution where the chance of success changes with every trial is called a poisson binomial distribution